# Me publica muchos valores vacios

Tags: angular, component

Estoy intentando generar un proyecto, donde tengo una serie de targets por un lado y una serie de artículos por otro. Entonces la idea es que me cargue aquellos artículos donde se encuentren esos targets y que si no coinciden que no muestren nada, para ello me he generado el siguiente código en el fichero HTML del componente:

```
<div *ngFor="let articulo of spiderService.articulos">
    <div *ngIf="articulo.titulo.includes(target.nombre)">
        <p *ngIf="true">{{articulo.titulo}} - test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Mi problema es que tengo más de 3.200 artículos y me carga el siguiente código:

```
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="card-stacked  col s12"></div>
```

Este div me lo genera 15 veces que es el número de targets que tengo en la base de datos, y dentro de este div me genera otros 3.200 divs uno por artículo, si coincide el título del artículo con el nombre del target me lo muestra perfecto en pantalla, pero los que no coinciden me genera ese div vacío, el cual me dá mucho problemas para el diseño y demás.

Comment: No veo ningún `div` con la clase que mencionas en tu código. Creo que debes actualizar el ejemplo para poder saber como se genera tu html

Comment: Tal como dice @devconcept, tu código no es claro. Sería bueno que colocaras tambien la función que estas utilizando para validar el primer `*ngIf`.